# SELECT LIMIT on a view in MySQL

Tags: mysql, view, limit

My problem is easy to explain:

```
SELECT * FROM sphinx LIMIT 512 OFFSET 1
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM sphinx LIMIT 512, 513
```

Will return row 0 to 512. Is there any way possible to return a specific row of a view?

Comment: isn't it `SELECT * FROM sphinx LIMIT 1 OFFSET 512` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sphinx LIMIT 1 OFFSET 512
```